# awk check variable with field following line

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm pretty new to AWK, and have question I hope someone can help me with:
I have the a pattern that looks something like this:

```
620
621
622
623
624
624 66.75, 150.13
625
625 67.24, 153.31
626
627
628
628 68.14, 151.98

etc,etc
```

Using an awk script I'm trying to achieve the following result: I want to remove the duplicates from my first column of numbers (a counter) and concatenate my data (2nd & 3rd column). So I would like my data to look like this:

```
620
621
622
623
624 66.75, 150.13
625 67.24, 153.31
626
627
628 68.14, 151.98
```

So far I have been trying stuff like storing the first field in a variable and then test if the following number is equal or not. But I think I would have to do something with going back one step and change the previous printed variable if a duplicate field is found. How can I do this using AWK? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to store the entire file in memory:

```
awk 'l==$1{$1=""; printf ",%s", $0; next}
  {l=$1; printf("%s%s", NR==1?"":"\n", $0)}
  END{ print ""}' input-file
```

Answer (score 2):

this line will work for your example:

```
 awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
620
621
622
623
624 66.75, 150.13
625 67.24, 153.31
626
627
628 68.14, 151.98
```

but note that `for (x in a)` will not guarantee to follow the same order in your file, though it worked for your example data in the question. If you want the result to be sorted by the 1st column. easiest way is pipe the awk output to a `sort -n` so we have:

```
 awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file|sort -n
```

Answer (score 1):

One small adjustment to Kent's code (Assuming multiple line can contain data)

```
awk '{i=$1;sub(/[0-9]*/,"");a[i]=sprintf("%s %s", a[i], $0);}END{for(x in a)printf("%s %s\n", x, a[x]);}' td | sort
```

If multiple rows can contain data this concatenates them together.